# Audio/video content match up and comparison

Tags: video, audio, comparison

As a multimedia collector/archivist I often have to compare several audio/video files which are ostensibly duplicates apart from being of different quality / originating from different sources. The differences may also include some tracks/clips having slightly longer intro or outro whereas the bulk of the content is the same. I then make decisions whether any files have no value on top of the others and so delete them.

Sometimes the content differences are rather obscure e.g. slightly different video frame cuts in the middle, or additional audio production artifacts (as opposed to mere mastering). These differences make the files different enough to declare them different versions and so to keep them all.

I am wondering if there are any tools that automate this sort of matching up / comparison and highlight differences in content while ignoring differences in quality? Surely the line dividing these two kinds of differences will sometimes be blurred so the tool would have to allow to adjust the sensitivity / fuzziness in telling one from the other.